# Error certificate build in unity for windows phone applications

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, certificate, windows-10-mobile

How can I fix that errors when I try to build my aplication with unity3d for windows phone 10.

The type or namespace name 'X509Certificates' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'X509Chain' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your settings from File->Build Settings. Select **Windows Store** and click **Player Settings**. On the right side, Change Scripting Backend from **.NET** to **IL2CPP**.

Comment: I change my backend script (.net to IL2CPP) but when I want to put on my device, failed. 
Zero succesful deploy @Programmer

Comment: 2 weeks later you are replying.....Does that mean the problem started 2 weeks later or was the problem already there? What error are you getting?

Comment: sorry, I think I can solve my problem, the same error with namespace, when set script backend .net, if I change to IL2CPP it's ok, done build, size on disk ~11GB.

Comment: If changing it to IL2CPP fixes the problem then stick to it for NOW. You can remove the use of `System.Security.Cryptography` if  you can't stay with IL2CPP. I think that Windows phone support for Unity is still in development stage and every feature is not supported. That's why you are getting X509Chain error.   "UnityException: Failed to run reference rewriter with command --target="Temp\StagingArea\itextsharp.dll" is a new error and has nothing to do with the original question so you have to ask a new question for that so that this post wont get long.

Comment: What Unity version are you using?

Comment: last version 5.3.4f1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109038/discussion-between-jijie-ciprian-and-programmer).

Comment: here, download unity 5.4.0B14. Change that back to .NET and see if that X509  error is gone. http://unity3d.com/unity/beta

Comment: Try it. Unity fixed lots of bugs in 5.4 for windows phone. Maybe be this is one of the bugs they fixed. So download it and try it.

Comment: I try but I have the same error @Programmer, another solution?

Comment: Unity is working hard right now on IL2CPP to reduce the size of the compiled file. At-thesma time they are working hard to supprt .NET 6.0 and that release will be at the end of the year. Right now, your only solution is to use the IL2CPP which compiles with huge file and works or remove any code that uses stuff from `System.Security.Cryptography` then compile to .NET. Why are do you need stuff from `System.Security.Cryptography`?

Comment: I used to validate an certificate on server

Comment: thanks a lot @Programmer, if you find a solution write here.

Comment: I don't think there is another solution this moment other than what I wrote above. But you can try this https://github.com/andyburke/UnityHTTP It works for Unity and it looks like it has Server SSL without `System.Security.Cryptography` and probably what you need. You can even post a question there if you are not sure.